# echo "${txtred}Text${txtrst}" color not always working

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, scripts

I have a .sh file through terminal and I'm using `echo "${txtred}Text${txtrst}"` as a display of what's happening when running the script. But sometimes the color is not red, although I used `{txtred}`. I don't know why? If anyone could advise why may be this is happening.

Comment: please be more specific, exactly under what situation does the color not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using *ANSI escape sequences*

They look somewhat like this in a `echo` command

```
$ echo -e "\e[COLORmSample Text\e[0m"
```

You have to use the *-e* flag to use these, however.

But with these you can change both **foreground** and **background** colors.

Have a look at *[this](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Bash-Colors)*